# How to upload multiple images using file tag?

Tags: html, file, input

I want to select multiple images from different folder in my system.

I have used the following code to select multiple images,

```
<input class="file" type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple="">
```

Here I am uploading multiple images from a single folder.

Example:

I have been selected 3 images from `d:` drive. If I want to add two more images from `e:` drive means, how can it be done?

Comment: You'll need to create more `<input>` tags, each with the Browse button.

Comment: Is it possible using the single `<input>` tag?

Comment: Certainly not if the files come from multiple directories. You might have luck selecting more files from one directory, but probably not; no big company does that. What they do is adding more input tags with Javascript on the fly.